# Getting Sum of multiple columns of multiple tables through group by and joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using following query to get sum of multiple columns from two tables using left join. But mysql shows an error of "Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function" Please point out where I am on mistake?

```
SELECT  url as Domain,
  A.advertiserid as advertiserid,
  count(A.salesId) as Impressions,
  Sum(IF(A.click1datetime IS NULL,0,1)) AS Clicks,
  sum(count(B.order_id)) as Sales,
  sum(sum(B.order_amount)) as SalesAmount,

  FROM  ClickRecords A
  left join SalesDetail B
  on A.salesId= B.salesId
  where
  A.advertiserid = 52 AND
  datetime >= '2012-03-01' AND
  datetime < '2012-03-02'
  group by advertiserid, Domain
  order by impressions desc;
```

Comment: It's because you've nested your sums - `SUM(COUNT` and `SUM(SUM` are not valid. Can you give more information on how your tables relate to each other and why you need `SUM(SUM(B.order_amount))` as opposed to `SUM(B.order_amount)`, and the same for `SUM(COUNT(B.order_id))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted above, you can't nest aggregation functions - ie. `sum(sum(value))` is not valid.

I think you want:

```
SELECT url as Domain,
       A.advertiserid as advertiserid,
       count(distinct A.salesId) as Impressions,
       count(distinct case when A.click1datetime IS NOT NULL then A.salesId end) 
            AS Clicks,
       count(B.order_id) as Sales,
       sum(B.order_amount) as SalesAmount,
FROM ClickRecords A
left join SalesDetail B on A.salesId= B.salesId
where A.advertiserid = 52 AND
      datetime >= '2012-03-01' AND
      datetime < '2012-03-02'
group by advertiserid, Domain
order by impressions desc;
```

Note the use of `count(distinct ...)` for ClickRecords values - `sum` or non-distinct `count` add up values based on numbers of non-null records, which could be multiplied by SalesDetail records (where there is more than one per ClickRecord).

Answer (score 1):

You can not use aggregation functions as parameters of other aggregation functions (for example: `sum(count(B.order_id))`).